# How to play a sound in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to play a sound in `Xamarin.Forms`?

I need to play a wav file.

[Here is a sample](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleAudioForms) for doing this but it has this error:

> The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly.

Comment: You misspelled `Forms`.
What error do you get?

Comment: The code in github repo that you link does work correctly (ie. there is no dependency service created for iOS. at all and thus a Null reference occurs on the dependency lookup). Use this one as a working example: https://github.com/srkrathore/AudioPlayEx

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your file is blocked for security reasons. Locate your file with Windows Explorer, then right-click it and select Properties. Click Unblock, Apply and OK [image: Unblock]

Plus, remove any non-English character from the filename.

[Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45275/error-msb4018-the-convertresourcescases-task-failed-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088094/Playing-audio-mp-File-in-Xamarin-Forms) of using Dependency Service to play Audio files in Xamarin.Forms (iOS and Android implementations).